# How to hide a Div in angular 4 with webApi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, angular2-template, angular2-forms

here i am using an angular 4 web application .here, if an image is on the file location show the image and else condition if the image is none show empty space.( do not show like this[image]   )
if any body please help me for this solution

**This is my Component.html file**

```
   <div class="figure-left col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
 <figure class="photo">
 <img [src]="product.ItemImage" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" />
                </figure>
            </div>
```

**this is my WebAPI**

```
....etc.........
  foreach (spSpecificItems_Result item in itemList)
            {
                ITemDetail objItem = new ITemDetail();
                var image = item.ItemImage;
                if (image != null)
                {
                    base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image);
                    htmlsrc = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

                }
                else
                {
//here else condition i want to show empty space in my output

                }

                objItem.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                objItem.ItemCode = item.ItemCode;
    etc ....etc....
```

Comment: is this ok if you show the default image if image not found?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the directive

```
<div class="figure-left col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" *ngIf="condition">
   <figure class="photo">
      <img [src]="product.ItemImage" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" />
   </figure>
</div>
```

if it is true it shows the block of otherwise it remains empty

Answer (score 0):

you can use either two of these methods

*ngIf will remove the element from DOM. when hidden attribute just change display property to none

`<img *ngIf="product.ItemImage" [src]="product.ItemImage" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block"/>`

`<img [hidden]="product.ItemImage" [src]="product.ItemImage" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block"/>`

or use onError for show default image if somethings gone wrong

`<img *ngIf="product.ItemImage" [src]="product.ItemImage" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block"
onError="this.src='./app/assets/images/placeholder.jpg';"  alt="..."/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom image class and set hight and width of the portion or you can also set a default image if the image is not available.

```
<div  class="col-md-6">
    <img  src="{{logo+''+data.image}}" alt="Item Image" height="150" width="200" style="min-height: 91px; max-width: 109px" onError="this.src='assets/images/users/medilogo.png';">
</div>
```

If the above code is not working just inform me so I can help you